# Yii2 restful not working

Tags: rest, yii2

By using [this link](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-quick-start.html) I tried to have a restful app, but it's not working and always returned this:

> Object not found!
>
> The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please > > check your spelling and try again.
>
> If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
>   Error 404
>   localhost
>   Apache/2.4.4 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1e PHP/5.5.1

I call it like this: `localhost/restful/web/users`

**Edit:**

This kind of call is not working either: `localhost/restful/web/?r=users`

It returned this:

> Not Found (#404)
>   Page not found.
>
> The above error occurred while the Web server was processing your request.
>
> Please contact us if you think this is a server error. Thank you.

Comment: Why you are specifying the full path with 'web'? Did you configure urls?

Comment: I configured url like this link http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-quick-start.html and because yii program will run in a url that contain web, I call it with web in path

Comment: can you please share the content of `config/web.php` and of your controller?

Comment: try adding frontend / backend if you are using advance temp.
http://localhost/restful/frontend/web/users

Comment: im using basic one, kshitiz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my `config/web.php`:

```
<?php

$params = require(__DIR__ . '/params.php');

$config = [
    'id' => 'basic',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],

    'components' => [
        'urlManager'=>[
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'enableStrictParsing' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [
                ['class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 'controller' => 'user'],
            ],
        ],
        'request' => [
            // !!! insert a secret key in the following (if it is empty) - this is required by cookie validation
            'cookieValidationKey' => 'a',
            'parsers' => [
                'application/json' => 'yii\web\JsonParser',
            ],
        ],
        'cache' => [
            'class' => 'yii\caching\FileCache',
        ],
        'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'app\models\User',
            'enableAutoLogin' => true,
        ],
        'errorHandler' => [
            'errorAction' => 'site/error',
        ],
        'mailer' => [
            'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
            // send all mails to a file by default. You have to set
            // 'useFileTransport' to false and configure a transport
            // for the mailer to send real emails.
            'useFileTransport' => true,
        ],
        'log' => [
            'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'db' => require(__DIR__ . '/db.php'),
    ],
    'params' => $params,
];

if (YII_ENV_DEV) {
    // configuration adjustments for 'dev' environment
    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'debug';
    $config['modules']['debug'] = 'yii\debug\Module';

    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'gii';
    $config['modules']['gii'] = 'yii\gii\Module';
}

return $config;
```

And the controller:

```
<?php

namespace app\controllers;

use yii\rest\ActiveController;

class UserController extends ActiveController{
    public $modelClass = 'app\models\User';
}
```

Also a created my model by gii.

The problem solved by enabling curl and using it in my controller.

Comment: by enabling curl and using it in my controller, the problem solved

Answer (score 1):

Have the same error (stil getting 404 Not found on each request) have solve it adding .htaccess to (my yii path)/web folder (the same where you have index.php):

```
# use mod_rewrite for pretty URL support
RewriteEngine on

# If a directory or a file exists, use the request directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Otherwise forward the request to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

This is because when you create an clean instance of Yii2 you don't have the .htaccess file (in my opinion probably the security reason).

for me the: (enabling curl and using it in my controller) installed via composer

```
composer require --prefer-dist linslin/yii2-curl "*"
```

use in controller

```
<?php

namespace app\controllers;

use yii\rest\ActiveController;
use linslin\yii2\curl;//this was added

class UserController extends ActiveController
{
```

Don't work.
Maybe this helps someone :)